# Item is disappearing from list in android

Tags: android, listview

I have an listview of SMSItem objects . When any new sms arrives , it is showed in the list . But after clicking the list or if the activity is relaunched , the item is disappearing . The item is not showed in the list .

My manifest file is as follows :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.commlink.smscheck"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" /> 

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SmsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

       <receiver
            android:name=".SmsBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".ShowIndividualSMS"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

          <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"
                android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" /> 
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming MMS messages -->
        <receiver android:name=".MmsReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Activity that allows the user to send new SMS/MMS messages -->
        <activity android:name=".ComposeSmsActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />                
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Service that delivers messages from the phone "quick response" -->
        <service android:name=".HeadlessSmsSendService"
                 android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"
                 android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

If the menifest file is as follows , then the item in list is not disappearing . But the app is not set as default .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.commlink.smscheck"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" /> 

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SmsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

       <receiver
            android:name=".SmsBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".ShowIndividualSMS"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming MMS messages -->
        <receiver android:name=".MmsReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Activity that allows the user to send new SMS/MMS messages -->
        <activity android:name=".ComposeSmsActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />                
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Service that delivers messages from the phone "quick response" -->
        <service android:name=".HeadlessSmsSendService"
                 android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"
                 android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Where is the problem . How can I solve this?

The code of the adapter is as follows :

```
public class SmsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SMSItem> {

    List<SMSItem> smsBody;
    Context context;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    String fromNumber;

    public SmsArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            List<SMSItem> smsBody, String fromNumber) {
        super(context, resource, smsBody);
        this.smsBody = smsBody;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.fromNumber = fromNumber;
    }

    public SMSItem getStr(int position) {
        return smsBody.get(position);
    }

    public void setRead(int position, String smsMessageId) {
        smsBody.get(position).status = true;
        SMSItem smsItem = smsBody.get(position);
        smsItem.status = true;
        //smsBody.set(position, smsItem);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("read",true);
        int flag = context.getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),
                values, "_id=" + smsMessageId, null);
        Toast.makeText(context, "The result is "+flag, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    

    /*   Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        String selection = "address = ? AND body = ? AND read = ?";
        String from = "03590000004";
        String body =smsItem.sms;
        String[] selectionArgs = {from, body, "0"};

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("read", true);

        int flag = context.getContentResolver().update(uri, values, selection, selectionArgs);
        Toast.makeText(context, "The result is "+flag, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   */

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public SMSItem getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return smsBody.get(position);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textfrom;
        public TextView text_sms;
        public TextView text_time;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //  Toast.makeText(context, "The index is "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.textfrom = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView_from);
            holder.text_sms = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView_sms);
            holder.text_time = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView_time);

            /************ Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textfrom.setText(" " + fromNumber);
        SMSItem smsItem = smsBody.get(position);
        String smsTextToDisplay = smsItem.sms;
        if (smsTextToDisplay.length() > 100)
            smsTextToDisplay = smsTextToDisplay.substring(0, 99) + " ...";

        holder.text_sms.setText(smsTextToDisplay);

        holder.text_time.setText(smsItem.time);
        if (smsItem.status == false) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                    R.color.light_blue_overlay));
        }
        else
        {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);    
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: how are you displaying the image? can you show us the adapter

Comment: The question is updated .